# Multiple lambda outputs in string replacement using apply [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of "states" from which I have to iterate:

`states = ['antioquia', 'boyaca', 'cordoba', 'choco']`

I have to iterate one column in a pandas df to replace or cut the string where the state text is found, so I try:

```
df_copy['joined'].apply([(lambda x:  x.replace(x,x[:-len(j)])  if x.endswith(j) and len(j) != 0 else x) for j in states])
```

And the result is:

[image: Result obtained]

Result wanted:

[image: Result wanted]

`joined` column is the input and the desired output is `p_joined` column

If it's possible also to find the state not only in the end of the string but check if the string contains it and replace it

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what your question asks:

```py
df_copy['p_joined'] = df_copy.joined.str.replace('(' + '|'.join(states) + ')$', '')
```

Output:

```
                             joined                 p_joined
0                   caldasantioquia                   caldas
1                  santafeantioquia                  santafe
2  medelinantioquiamedelinantioquia  medelinantioquiamedelin
3                  yarumalantioquia                  yarumal
4  medelinantioquiamedelinantioquia  medelinantioquiamedelin
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was trying all day to solve it until I finally gave up and asked